# Significant Friedman's Test, but non-significant post-hocs?

Tags: nonparametric, wilcoxon-signed-rank

I have a sample of 25 in my within-subjects design, with my DV as error rates. The data contains a lot of zeros (i.e. no errors) and is highly negatively skewed, so I can't run the repeated-measure ANOVA as I hoped. So I ran a Friedman's Test for my 6 conditions and got a significant result (p = .000).

Then I ran three Wilcoxon Signed Rank tests (and set the significance at .05/3 = .016), but NONE of the results are significant (not even at the unadjusted .05 level. One pair comes close though around p =.058).

Is this a power issue? Can it be resolved? And if not, which should I report (the Friedman's or the Wilcoxon's) ?

Comment: "The data contains a lot of zeros" ... and so would be unsuitable for the procedures you're using - they both assume continuous data, at least in their original versions (does your software handle the heavy level of ties properly?). But in any case, there's no good reason to expect that a signed rank test done pairwise will always reject when the Friedman does, even unadjusted (I'd report both if I did them). Are the references [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedman_test#Post_hoc_analysis) of any help to you?

Comment: Damn. I'm using spss. Would a log transformation (so lowest values are at least 1.00) allow me to use these tests then? I will have to try to locate some of those references at the library this week.

Comment: A log transformation is a *terrible* idea, since taking log(0) is going to leave you with non-numeric values. If SPSS deals with that the way most software will, that will lose a lot of your data.

Comment: Why must your post hocs match your omnibus test? Such mismatches are fairly common (we have dozens of questions relating to that, for various tests).

Comment: I can live with the post hoc not matching, but I have to be able to run some test of comparison between the conditions. Can I still do the friedmans test with zeros but not the post hocs, or were you including the friedman test when you said it requires continuous data?

Comment: Also I won't be taking log(0),because  I'll add a constant term when computing the transformation (such that the lowest output value will be 1.00) ,by using the log 10 (k-x), where x is the largest value in the set and K is x+10?

Comment: The Friedman as normally done assumes continuous data. However, it's not especially sensitive to moderate numbers of ties. In your case that may not be so helpful. In small samples it's quite possible to do an "exact test" by computing the null distribution (the permutation distribution under the null) of the test statistic given the pattern of ranks - the question is whether the software does it. In larger samples it's possible to compute the effect on the variance. Again, the question is whether the software you're using does this. (It should tell you!)  ...ctd

Comment: ctd ... Adding a constant avoids the $\log(0)$ giving $-\infty$ issue ... but it doesn't solve your problem of heavy ties at $0$ -- it just *moves* it to $\log(c)$ where $c$ is the constant you added! What's the benefit of that?

Comment: [This article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC468904/) discusses both the effect of ties and post-hoc tests for the Friedman (among a couple of other nonparametric procedures).